# Forcing specific character input using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a regex in java script to validate a full name field. I need the validation to accept 1 or more instances for any `[a-z A-Z]` characters and also the field MUST include a `-` and a space character.

The current regex i am using is : `("^[a-zA-Z\\-\\\s]*$");`

This regex is allowing the correct input for what i want, however, it does not force the user to insert a space and a - which i need my validation to include. I am very new to regex and was only introduced to them yesterday so i do not fully understand the correct use of certain characters.

I also do not want the space and - to be at the start or end of the field and not directly next to each other.

examples of valid input:

```
John smi-th
dereK al-jamone
ro-binstanle y
```

I know this validation is unusual but I would be very grateful for any help to enable me to get a better understanding of regex.

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether I understand your requirement correctly:

- One or more of `a-z`, `A-Z`, space (ASCII 32). Exactly one `-`
- Space and hyphen `-` cannot be at start or end of the string, but there must be one space and one hyphen `-`, so the string must start and end with alphabet character.
- Hyphen `-` and space cannot be next to each other. *I assume consecutive space and consecutive `-` are also not allowed.*

For the above requirement, this regex should validate the string:

```
^(?!.*[- ]{2})(?=.* )[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*-[a-zA-Z ]*[a-zA-Z]$
```

Short explanation:

- `(?!.*[- ]{2})`: Assert that hyphen and space are not next to each other, and also disallow consecutive spaces and hyphens.
- `(?=.* )`: Check that at least one space is in the string
- `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*-[a-zA-Z ]*[a-zA-Z]`: According to my analysis above, the first and last character are alphabet character (and they can't be at the same position in the string) - this will disallow space and hyphen implicitly. Only 1 hyphen is allowed and the rest are any number of alphabet and space.

You can also write this with multiple regex - the code will be slightly clearer:

```
// No hyphen and space at the beginning and the end. Exactly 1 hyphen.
// The string only contains alphabet, space and hyphen
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*-[a-zA-Z ]*[a-zA-Z]$/.test(str) &&
// Hyphen and space cannot be directly next to each other
// Consecutive hyphens, or consecutive spaces are also disallowed
!/[- ]{2}/.test(str) &&
// At least one space in the string, can be replaced with indexOf
/ /.test(str)
```

Comment: @dystroy: `I need the validation to accept 1 or more instances for any [a-z A-Z] characters and also the field MUST include a - and a space character.` The set doesn't include `-`, so I assume exactly one.

Comment: +1 I'm not sure about the spec (I don't read it as you) but your regex seems to work. I think the answer would be better with a detailed explanation (of the lookahead for example).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
^[A-Za-z\s]+(-(?!-)[A-Za-z\s]+)+$
```

Comment: Space is not allowed in your regex. Have you tested it with OP's example?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to ensure that only one space and one hyphen can be present then I would opt for checking two different regex, if either match then it is valid...

with the space BEFORE the hyphen...

```
^[a-zA-Z]*\s.[a-zA-Z]*\-.[a-zA-Z]*$
```

with the space AFTER the hyphen

```
^[a-zA-Z]*\-.[a-zA-Z]*\s.[a-zA-Z]*$
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/YvsWh/)